# why does the models.objects.filter take less time then the models.objects.get?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

## Even though filter work with number of object's why is it fast?

as we all see that the filter gives you the queryset  but the get method gives you the single object
but having queryset is not equal to having all the object even after having queryset if i select single object by slicing(without loop) or using get method to select the object

i tryed to get time difference

```
from time import time

   def f1():
    t0 = time()
    User.objects.filter(username='risha')
    print("Execution time of f1: {}".format(time() - t0))

def f2():
    t0 = time()
    User.objects.get(username='risha')
    print("Execution time of f2: {}".format(time() - t0))
f1()
f2()
```

so the conclusion is
Execution time of f1: 0.0009980201721191406
Execution time of f2: 0.0029938220977783203

but why the filter take less time even though it works with more object?

Comment: Try profiling by running the code many times in a loop (say 1000 or 10000) if you want to try to get a sense of the difference in time taken between the two options.

Comment: why the filter take less time even though it works with more object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QuerySet` which `User.objects.filter(username='risha')` returns are lazily evaluated.

That means that unless you time `list(User.objects.filter(username='risha'))` you are not performing any real database query.

Comment: what does get do ? if filter is better then get even wana work with single object so what is the use of get?

Comment: filter will return a list of items. As far as I know it is not better. It looks faster in your bench because it doesn't perform the database query !